# Is std::move overkill in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if using the `std::move()` in this example is overkill or computationally more expensive than simply copying it? I would really like to know.

```
class Student
{
    private: 
        std::string _studentName;
        int _studentGrade;
    public:
        Student() : _studentName("No Name"), _studentGrade(0) {}

        std::string Name() const { return _studentName; }
        void Name(std::string x) { _studentName = std::move(x); }

        int Grade() const { return _studentGrade; }
        void Grade(int x) { _studentGrade = std::move(x); }
};
```

Comment: Why not make the parameter a const reference and assign by copy in the string version?

Comment: I know that, I am wondering whether std::move is overkill.

Comment: `std::move` on `int` is fairly pointless and likely to get optimized to a copy anyway. The `Name` method takes its value by parameter and then uses `std::move`. You're copying *and* moving, which is of course strictly worse than either copying or moving. I would agree with dave's comment that copying inside the method is better, and not moving.

Comment: Try to think about it in terms of ownership. `std::move` implies "I'm giving you ownership of this thing; I don't need it anymore". Odds are, you're not passing ownership of a string; you're making a new one to be owned by the `Student`. In that situation, copying is appropriate. If you're really worried, you can provide a version which takes a `std::string&&` as well as the copy version so the user can opt-in to move semantics if they wish.

Comment: @dave That change would penalize any use of the `Name` setter that would receive an rvalue. It would force a needless copy.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo An `int` move is the same thing as an `int` copy. There is no such thing as optimizing an `int` move to a copy.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `std::string x` won't be a copy if the argument was passed as an rvalue.

Comment: Adding to @FrançoisAndrieux: The standard reference on preferring pass-by-value is [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: The basic question would be if a copy would be *costly*. Which it could be if it contains a lot of data (like when you copy a voxel image of a million cells) or when you execute the operation in question a million times. Assuming that the name of a student won't have the volume of a book and that you don't have a million students, yes, it is overkill. Copying this takes nanoseconds. The right question is what is most *readable*. That said, a move is still readable, so that is fine. But with your argument not being at least a reference, it is pointless.

Comment: Another important aspect: do you really want to move? What if I want to go like `string type = "dog"; Animal dog1, dog2; dog1.type(type); dog2.type(type);`? In this case, `type` would be an empty string after the first usage.

Comment: @Aziuth: Not as written, no. The argument is being received by value, so it's copied when you call; the original `type` is never moved-from.

Comment: @ShadowRanger By asking him if he really wants to move, I was talking about the desired behaviour. Not about the actual behaviour, which I already mentioned to be bugged. The important point is that that even if the code was working as he intended it to, there are reasons to do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [core guidelines at F.call: Parameter passing](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#fcall-parameter-passing), we can deduce a few recommendations.

Use move only when you want to optimize for rvalue. If you find that it does an improvement on performance, it's up to you to do it.

You could receive by value then move as it optimises rvalues calls into your setters, but it pessimizes lvalues. This is because `std::string` will reuse its storage and not cause unnecessary allocations when copying from the const reference. Copying into the value parameter always end up allocating when no SSO is possible.

The preferred way, especially for setters are to use const reference, and add an rvalue reference overload when rvalues are passed into the setter:

```
class Student
{
    private: 
        std::string _studentName;
        int _studentGrade;
    public:
        Student() : _studentName("No Name"), _studentGrade(0) {}

        std::string_view Name() const { return _studentName; }
        void Name(std::string const& x) { _studentName = x; }

        // add this when you need to optimize for rvalues.
        // optimizing for rvalues is not always needed.
        // They can speedup quite a bit when actually needed.
        void Name(std::string&& x) { _studentName = std::move(x); }

        // int is a trivial type, so move does nothing. No move needed.
        int Grade() const { return _studentGrade; }
        void Grade(int x) { _studentGrade = x; }
}
```

For the int, `std::move` won't do anything, it's still a copy. Just take them by value and return them by value.

However, the best you can do is much simpler:

```
class Student
{
public:
    std::string studentName;
    int studentGrade;
};
```

Since your setters don't enforce any invariants, you'd be better off using public members. You don't need overloads and reference since `std::string` implements it for you.

Comment: The original avoids copies for rvalues and also only copies once for lvalues. I'm not sure this version is an improvement.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it is. When calling the setter with the const ref, it's not always an allocation. The string will reuse its previous storage. With by-value + move only, if you pass in lvalues repeatedly, it's always an allocation since you always need to copy. So for setters, you better use references only. For constructor, passing by value + move is the best.

Comment: Passing an rvalue won't lead to any allocations. `x` is move constructed from the argument, which will reuse the original argument's storage. `_studentName` will then reuse that storage. The only allocation was for the original argument. If you pass it as an rvalue that allocation was going to be disposed of anyway.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux when you pass rvalues only yes, passing by value + move is pretty much equivalent. However, by value + move is much much worse for lvalues than a const ref. That's why, for setters, you better simply add an overload for rvalue reference. This is also what the core guidelines states.

Comment: It is not significantly slower to pass by value when the argument is an lvalue. Using by-value you get a copy + a move. Using `const` reference you save a move. If the extra move matters, you can put in the overloads but if you are only going to have a single overload the pass-by-value is a better overall general solution. Edit : Note that this applies to sink functions only which maintain ownership of the argument, like a setter.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's not an extra move, it's an extra *copy*. Passing by const ref then assigning don't always allocate. Passing by value from from an lvalue always allocate. [The core guideline warn about potential slowdown](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f16-for-in-parameters-pass-cheaply-copied-types-by-value-and-others-by-reference-to-const)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223768/discussion-between-francois-andrieux-and-guillaume-racicot).

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot there is only an extra move as copy would have to trigger anyways or not at all in either case. In most cases it is totally fine to replace `fun(const obj&)` + `fun(obj&&)` with `fun(obj)` as at most you add a single move operation which is likely to be optimized anyways and you reduce amount of code written. Only exceptions are when move construction is non-trivial and when you define move/copy construction or assignment. `std::string` happens to have a complex move assignment so in this particular case it might be an improvement but in general it isn't worthwhile.

Comment: @ALX23z when using `fun(obj)` (by value setter) then you make setting from lvalue much worse than `fun(obj const&)`. If you call a setter in a loop, it most likely won't do any allocation at all if the setter uses const ref. This is not the case with taking by value. If your setter take by value and you call it in a loop with an lvalue, you allocate *everytime*, not just the fist couple of times. So unless you're okay pessimizing lvalues, I would advise setters to take by const ref instead.

Comment: I carefully mentionned setters as they are pretty much the only that will benefit from that. Constructors and functions that push back in a container are not subject to this, and taking by value is totally fine.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot but in each call one applies `studentName = obj` which is the same as copying. Perhaps if copy-assignment is optimized and reuses former allocation then it can save something.

Comment: @ALX23z Yes indeed. `studentName = obj` may not reallocate as it reuses previously allocated storage. However, copying into a value parameter always allocate. Receiving containers by value in setters pessimizes lvalues.